# How do I get the bundle name by route?

Tags: 9

I would like to pass variables to twig that depend on certain routes or node types (bundles) (a user page, a comment, a page or a custom content type). I used the name of the route (`entity.comment.edit_form`, `entity.user.canonical`) for that purpose.

Now I need to exclude some node types (i.e. I can't use just `entity.node.canonical` for all cases, I need to create a special condition for certain types of nodes). How do I get node type (bundle?) by route name/object?

My code is in the `.theme` file in `HOOK_preprocess_page(&$variables)`

UPD: Okay, I have discovered that there is actually `$variables['node']` which contains what I need in `$variables['node']->getType()`

But let's say I have just the route, how do I get an ID from it and load a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal is providing such a variable for the html template:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for HTML document templates.
 */
function node_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // If on an individual node page or node preview page, add the node type to
  // the body classes.
  if (($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) || ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_preview'))) {
    if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) {
      $variables['node_type'] = $node->getType();
    }
  }
}
```

This code works in your `HOOK_preprocess_page(&$variables)` as well.

UPD: `getParameter('node')` gets already a loaded node. So you don't need to get the ID to load the node, but if you need the ID then use `getRawParameter('node')`.